# Why tab bar upper half's color is lighter than bottom half

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I create a navigation tab bar on the bottom of iphone and use dark gray color as tint color. Every things is good except the upper half's color is a bit lighter than bottom half. I also didn't fix it by programmatically set background color and tint color in viewDidLoad. This problem happen both of simulator and my iphone 5

[image]

[image: tab bar setting in storyboard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This effect was added by the system in the default way, not a bug or problem.

You can custom UITabBar in this way:

```
 tabController.tabBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"TabBarBG"];
```

Not only reset the background color or tint color.Have a try.

Answer (score 0):

That's the visual effect "gradient" added automatically by system. You can write a custom tab bar yourself to change the effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is default behavior of tab bar.

However you may change this by setting bakgroundimage for tab bar.